# Why do the fields of the selected form return the value "none" and "null" in the database?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to save a value in two fields, but when saving them I change the value to `none` and the db also shows me `null`.

I have tried to change the parentheses to square brackets, seeing if the 2 values ​​of the form are taken to the database, but I don't quite understand the difference between `form.cleaned_data()` and `form.cleaned_data[]`, but by doing so with the square brackets, it generates an error.

views.py

```
def solit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
        form = addiForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            peticion = form.save(commit=False)
            peticion.usuario = request.user
            peticion.save()
            peticion.usuario.d_pendientes = form.cleaned_data.get('d_pendientes')
            peticion.usuario.h_pendientes = form.cleaned_data.get('h_pendientes')
            peticion.usuario.save() 
            print (peticion.usuario.d_pendientes)
            print (peticion.usuario.h_pendientes)  
            return JsonResponse({'status': 'true', 'msg': 'Procesado Correctamente'})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'status': 'false', 'msg': 'Los datos no son validos'})
    form = addiForm()
    return render(request, 'plantillas/adicionar.html', {'form':form})
```

my models.py

```
class Usuarios(AbstractUser):
    numero_empleado = models.IntegerField(null= True, blank= True)
    area = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null= True, blank= True)
    d_pendientes = models.IntegerField(null= True, blank= False)
    h_pendientes = models.IntegerField(null= True, blank= False)
    f_init = models.DateField(max_length = 200,null= True, blank= True)
    init_vac = models.DateField(max_length = 200, null= True, blank= True)
    fin_vac = models.DateField(max_length = 200, null= True, blank= True)
    ul_vac_tomadas = models.IntegerField(null= True, blank= True)


class Peticion(models.Model):
    solit_choices = (
    ('Adicionar','Adicionar'),
)
    solicitudes_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(Usuarios, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    petit = models.CharField(max_length = 255, choices=solit_choices, null=True, blank=False)
    fec = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    razon = models.TextField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    periodo_init = models.DateField(max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True)
    periodo_fin = models.DateField(max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True)
    dias_adicion = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=False)
    horas_adicion = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=False)
```

forms.py

```
class addiForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        """Formulario de solicitud"""

        model = Peticion

        fields = [

            'solicitudes_id',
            'petit',
            'razon',
            'periodo_init',
            'periodo_fin',
            'dias_adicion',
            'horas_adicion',

    ]
```

In the console I can see, that he is receiving the POST request, but it also prints the value ​​`none` and not the values that I enter in the form inputs.

Comment: form.cleaned_data[] it's not the string that you are trying to slice it can't be sliced that's y error  and also it is not an list and it does not contain any index

Comment: Thank you very much for your response and I understand, but then how do I save the value of the field?

Answer (score 0):

by doing so you can easily save the forms values

```
 if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
                    user = user_form.save()
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.cleaned_data